# Suppress the duplicate values in group, SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, duplicate-data, suppression

I have an SSRS report
where the date should be grouped by project category
the project code in the category is repeating in side the group how do I suppress the value

Please help me to get an idea.

Thanks,brijit

Answer (score 7):

You can also hide fields by putting an expression in the Hidden property like this:

```
=Fields!ProductCode.Value = Previous(Fields!ProductCode.Value)
```

So if the value in the previous record is the same as this one, it will hide the field. You must sort the dataset correctly for this to work. In your case I think the sorting would be Date, ProductCategory, ProductCode.

In the past I used this often together with expressions for field borders to group the output visually.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is one option hide duplicates in properties in ssrs. so you will check in that option under the project category group.so that you can hide the duplicate values and get unique records. first u create one group based on project category in fields properties and then check in that hide duplicate option under that group.whenever you check in that option it will high light one drop down list showing containing group or dataset there you select your created group.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late for you brijt, but what I do is edit the textbox properties for that field, in the font tab enter an expression for Color as follows:

```
=IIf(Fields!ProductCode.Value = Previous(Fields!ProductCode.Value), "White", "Black")
```

...assuming your background is white this will effectively do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be an issue concerning the way you are grouping the dates.  Do you have the grouped with time on them as well but suppressing the hours in your output?

For example:

12-5-2010 12:00:00

12-5-2010 13:00:00

if you strip the times off in how you see them but not how you group them, they would show up duped.